# Enable logs in MAMP 3

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I want to log all mysql queries and also slower queries.

I found this doc - https://documentation.mamp.info/en/documentation/mamp/

But I found only error logs

How can I enable / have all logs about mysql php and apache?

Answer (score 2):

First, backup `/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh`

Next, pop open `/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh` in your favorite text editor

You should see something like this:

```
# /bin/sh
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe --port=3306 --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --lower_case_table_names=0 --pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid --log-error=/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log &
```

> You want to add in this string to that command:

```
--log-slow-queries=/Applications/MAMP/logs/slow_query_log
```

So the file contents should look like:

```
# /bin/sh
# /bin/sh /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe --port=3306 --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --lower_case_table_names=0 --pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid --log-slow-queries=/Applications/MAMP/logs/slow_query_log --log-error=/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log &
```

and then

1. **Save** out the file
2. **restart MAMP**
3. start hitting pages and **monitor the file**,
   `/Applications/MAMP/logs/slow_query_log`

This should be fine for MAMP 1.4.1. YMMV may vary, depending on your MySQL version.

> *The concept is the same, but the syntax can change in later versions.*

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: If this help please **[ACCEPT** it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)